# Nested PHP while loop to create a dynamic table that is 2 rows by 5 columns per row

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, html-table

My current code looks like this:

```
<?php

$i = 6; //will be pulled from a database
if ($i != "10") {
$countb = (10-$i);

}
echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"left\">";
echo "<tr><th>Results</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while ( $i != 0) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "Good";
    echo "</td>";
    $i= $i- 1;
}
while ( $countb != 0) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "not good";
    echo "</td>";
    $countb= $countb- 1;
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

This creates a 1 column 10 row table. I want to have two rows and 5 columns per row. Basically, if the user does not have 10 good marks I want to fill in the missing goods with not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be simplified, semantically improved, and more flexibly extended to use any possible score and stay with the 5 col format.

```
<?php
// this is the total possible score
$possibleScore = 10;

// this is the actual score
$i = 6; //will be pulled from a database

// semantically complete html table
echo "
<table border='1' align='left'>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Results</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>";

// rate every step from zero to total possible score
for ($ix=0;$ix<$possibleScore;$ix++) {

  // new row every 5 cols, but not first row
  if ($ix !== 0 && $ix % 5 === 0)
    echo "</tr>\n    <tr>";

  // good if index less than score
  if($ix<$i)
    echo "<td>Good</td>";
  else
    echo "<td>not good</td>";
}

echo "</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
";
```

Results in this output:

```html
<table border='1' align='left'>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Results</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Good</td><td>not good</td><td>not good</td><td>not good</td><td>not good</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But now you're free to substitute any values in for total score and actual score while still maintaining the reporting ratio.

```
// this is the total possible score
$possibleScore = 18;

// this is the actual score
$i = 11; //will be pulled from a database
```

Results in this:

```html
<table border='1' align='left'>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Results</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td><td>Good</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Good</td><td>not good</td><td>not good</td><td>not good</td><td>not good</td></tr>
    <tr><td>not good</td><td>not good</td><td>not good</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want, but do you want something like this?

```
<?php
    $d = 6; //will be pulled from a database
    $i=10;
    $c=$i; //c is 10
    if ($d != $i) {
      $countb = (10-$d);
    }
    echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"left\">";
    echo "<tr><th>Results</th>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    while ( $i != 0) {
        if($i>$countb){
          echo "<td>";
          echo "Good";
          echo "</td>";
        }
        if($i==($c/2)+1){
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if($i<=$countb){
            echo "<td>";
            echo "not good";
            echo "</td>";
        }
        $i=$i-1;
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: The formatting is correct however, I think there is an issue in the math you used. If i =6 then there should be 6 good and 4 not good. So basically on row 1 there would be 5 goods and on row 2 there be 1 good and 4 not good. Thanks