# display dynamic data in multiple columns

Tags: sql, layout, dynamic

I use an html string in php to display sql query results in a single column:
[image: single]

How can I use multiple columns to lay it out like this:
[image]

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $desc = $row['description'];
                $link = $row['link'];

                $output .= '<a href="' . $link . '">
                            <h3>' . $title . '</h3>
                                <p>' . $desc . '</p>
                            </a>';
            }
```

Comment: Add your codes in your question. The answer will depend on how you print the data from the DB.

Comment: edited @hungrykoala

Comment: Do you want a bootstrap answer?

Comment: That will be fine, if bootstrap is a good way of doing this

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3791082/6444625) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37638127/6444625)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [hungrykoala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6444625/hungrykoala) for help on this one

```
            $i = 0 ;
            $resultsPerRow = 2 ;
            $output = '<tr>';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
                $i++;
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $desc = $row['description'];
                $link = $row['link'];
                $output .= '<td><a href="' .$link. '">' .$title. '<br>' .$desc. '</a></td>';    

                if ($i % $resultsPerRow == 0) {     
                $output .= '</tr><td><br></td><tr>'; 
                }                   
            }
        echo($output);
```

Then output to a table tag

Comment: I change the ouput to traditional CSS, HTML to make it responsive, just like WP themes.